# Stream data aggregation sorted by timestamp

Tags: messaging, distributed-caching, nosql-aggregation, stream-processing, nosql

I have a use case where I am receiving events from the client and some of these events are logically related (belong to a single session), and there is a definite ordering among events based on timestamp.

Now, I want to build a solution that would should continue aggregating events until the last one of a particular group is received in increasing order of timestamp. So, if an event not in order is received, it should be held on until the events before them, are received. And then, go ahead with storing that in a data store such as HBase based on the key of that particular group.

The problem is the number of such incomplete groups at a time can be in the millions, and would need something that can support fast appending to the incomplete group and holding the events received unordered. How should I go about this?

Comment: Any little insight would be appreciable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you could use event stream processing or complex event processing frameworks http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_event_processing. you write a query/pattern, load it in the engine, feed engine with events and the query is being continually updated or fires when the time comes.

I like Codehaus Esper, it's open source, but restricted in unpaid version, I had to implement storing of events and reloading them on application start for example. another option is Drools Fusion, but I found it buggy when I tried it out some 5 years ago. I was looking into WSO2 CEP recently but this thing is seriously underdocumented.